# Add link to wordpress field data

Tags: custom-field

This code displays "@ fielddata" how I can add link to the artist?
Link is "https://rule34cartoon.com/?s=fielddata" .

```
<center>
<?php
$artist = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'artist', true);
if ( $artist ) :
    echo '© ' . $artist;
endif;
?>
</center>
```

Comment: That's not a link to the artist, it's a link to the search page. You could get that with `get_search_link( $artist )`. But I expect you really mean something better than that?

Comment: If people search for that field they can find all posts that have that field data.